# Состояние модального окна по умолчанию

Tags: javascript

Есть модальное окно, при клике на кнопку открываю его и выполняю какие-то действия, которые мне нужны и закрываю его. Идея в том чтобы при каждом открытии загружалось всплювающее окно по умолчанию, без каких-либо значений. Идею со значениями реализовал через `map`, но не подумал наперед что буду работать и с атрибутами, то есть удалять/добавлять классы и т.д. Как лучше организовать это?

Пробовал при загрузке страницы получать весь `html` модального окна и перед открытием его заменять содержимое,но перестали работать стилизованные выпадающие списки и выбор даты отвалился почему-то.

```
<div id="modal-1" class="modal-1 modal styled-2 track-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <h4>Track panel</h4>
            <i class="modal-action modal-close btn_close icon-close"></i>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <form id="book-time-form">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="wrapp-input ">
                            <select name="reason" class="m-styled v-reason">
                                <option value="">Choose action</option>
                                <?php if($reasons) : foreach($reasons as $reason) : ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $reason['id']; ?>"><?php echo $reason['name']; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6">
                        <div class="wrapp-input">
                            <input type="text" name="start_date" class="datepicker-from input-val v-start-date" placeholder="From">
                            <i class="add-icon to-right icon-calendar"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrapp-input">
                            <input type="text" name="end_date" class="datepicker-to input-val v-end-date" placeholder="To">
                            <i class="add-icon to-right icon-calendar"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6">
                        <div class="wrapp-input">
                            <select class="m-styled v-first-part" name="start_part">
                                <?php if($day_parts) : foreach($day_parts as $key => $part) : ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $part; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" wrapp-input ">
                            <select class="m-styled v-second-part" name="end_part">
                                <?php if($day_parts) : foreach($day_parts as $key => $part) : ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $part; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="wrapp-input">
                            <textarea name="reason_message" placeholder="Reason (optional)"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col 12">
                        <button id="book-time" type="button" class="btn mt-25 bg-blue w-auto ">Send request</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col 12 hide already-exist-error">Some days are already noted in this period</div>

                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-forgot -->
```

Решил проблему с помощью шаблонизатора `Jsrender`. Само всплывающее окно поместил в теги  как шаблон и перед каждым вызовом создаю заново это модальное окно.

```
var modalTpl = $('#modal-tpl');

var result = modalTpl.render({});
$('#modal-1').html(result);
datepickerInit();
initializeSelect();
$('#modal-1').openModal();
```

Comment: уберите php, дайте код по существу вопроса.